# Cannot connect NoSQLClient in Docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, terminal, pymongo

I am running mongo as well as mongoclient/mongoclient docker services in my Macbook.

```
➜  ~ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
40b69cb63c1d        mongoclient/mongoclient   "./entrypoint.sh nod…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp     clever_golick
57ba76f4340f        mongo                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago       Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   cranky_villani
```

The starting commands are :

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -e MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/pymongo_test" mongoclient/mongoclient

docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

I access the mongo server and can add a collection using pymongo in Python with

```
from pymongo import MongoClient   
mongo_client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
mongodb = mongo_client.pymongo_test
channel_table = mongodb.channel_table
data = {"col1":"something","col2":"something2"}
channel_table.insert_one(data)
```

I can execute this python succesfully without any Mongo Connection issues. I verified that the data is added in pymongotest DB using Robo 3T (https://robomongo.org/).

But when I ran the mongoclient on localhost:3000, I cannot see any data being added. 
Some details of inside **mongo** Image

```
➜  ~ docker exec -it eb265221846d bash
root@eb265221846d:/# printenv
HOSTNAME=eb265221846d
GPG_KEYS=E162F504A20CDF15827F718D4B7C549A058F8B6B
PWD=/
HOME=/root
GOSU_VERSION=1.11
MONGO_VERSION=4.2.2
MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org
TERM=xterm
MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org
SHLVL=1
MONGO_MAJOR=4.2
JSYAML_VERSION=3.13.0
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

inside **mongoclient/mongoclient** Image :

```
➜  ~ docker exec -it 6674c0109b7b bash 
node@6674c0109b7b:/opt/meteor/dist/bundle$ printenv
NODE_VERSION=8.4.0
HOSTNAME=6674c0109b7b
TERM=xterm
INSTALL_MONGO=true
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/opt/meteor/dist/bundle
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/pymongo_test
APP_BUNDLE_DIR=/opt/meteor/dist
BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR=/opt/build_scripts
ROOT_URL=http://localhost
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/node
MONGOCLIENT_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=
APP_SOURCE_DIR=/opt/meteor/src
MONGOCLIENT_CONNECTIONS_FILE_PATH=/opt/meteor/dist/predefined_connections.json
GOSU_VERSION=1.10
PORT=3000
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer in mongo client `MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/pymongo_test"` it mean localhost of the mongo client, no the mongo container.

You need docker network, you can run with legacy `linking`, but better to use docker-compose that do care of all these thing.

You can try this

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

[docker compose for mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

and in your python app seems like its running outside of container, so you can then connect with mongo using `mongo_client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')` , but in container localhost mean this container.

you can also try with moongose client.

```
services:
    mongodb:
      image: mongo:latest
      container_name: mongodb
      hostname: mongodb
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
    mongoclient:
      image: mongoclient/mongoclient:latest
      container_name: mongoclient
      hostname: mongoclient
      depends_on:
        - mongodb
      ports:
        - 3300:3000
```

Comment: docker network was an ideal thing. I was able to get everything get working.

Answer (score 1):

As @Adiii mentioned, `docker-compose` can really help in these scenarios, because it takes a lot of the networking headache out of things. I'll outline how this works in vanilla docker.

First, localhost. Containers are their own little networks, that means they have their own external interface (eth0), and they also have their own localhost. Thus, when you call localhost in a container, it's not calling the host machine's localhost, it's the *container's* localhost. You need to be able to call external to the container to reach out and find another service.

Container names become extremely helpful here. Containers are ephemeral, and should not be taken as having fixed ip addresses, and their names are randomly generated as well, unless otherwise specified. The names are able to be looked up in routing tables when you do an http request:

```sh
# I'll just run a sample httpbin service as an example
docker run -d -p 80:80 kennethreitz/httpbin

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                NAMES
a93a1ab833f6        kennethreitz/httpbin   "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0…"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   sleepy_brattain
```

Scrolling all the way to the right, you'll see the container was assigned the name `sleepy_brattain`. Now, if I go into `python`:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('http://sleepy_brattain')
r
<Response [200]>
```

I get a 200. This means that if you fix the names of your containers, you have a reference point to look them up with. I'll name my httpbin container `testbin`:

```sh
docker run -d --name testbin -p 80:80 kennethreitz/httpbin

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                NAMES
ead322a3d53f        kennethreitz/httpbin   "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0…"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   testbin
```

Note the name in the last column. Now if I run a python container, I can make an http get request against that name and it will work:

```sh
docker run -it python:3.6 /bin/bash

$ python -m pip install requests
$ python

>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://testbin')
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

However, for your mongo example to work, there's one last piece you'll need, and that's a `network`. Creating a network is easy:

```sh
docker network create mongo
```

And then, for containers to be able to see one another, you assign them to that network. For `mongo`:

```sh
docker run -d --network mongo -p 27017:27017 --name mymongo mongo

docker run -it --network mongo python:3.6
$ python -m pip install pymongo
$ python
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient('mongodb://mymongo:27017')
```

And I will know that a connection took place, because checking the logs:

```sh
docker logs $(docker ps -aq --filter "ancestor=mongo") | tail -n 3
2019-12-21T05:32:08.002+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
2019-12-21T05:32:50.773+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.18.0.3:34346 #1 (1 connection now open)
2019-12-21T05:32:50.773+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.18.0.3:34346 conn1: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.10.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "x86_64", version: "4.9.184-linuxkit" }, platform: "CPython 3.6.8.final.0" }
```

I see a connection from my python container

Comment: I was able to get it working with docker-compose with network. Also I am using the Python script in my host, not inside any of the docker VMs.